# How to download the answers to my questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I understand the use of data Explorer to get my questions. However I can't get the accepted answers to the questions.

My query is as follows in the data explorer:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##MyAccountID##

SELECT Posts.Tags,Posts.Title,Posts.Body
FROM Posts
WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
```

How do I get the accepted answers as well?

Answer (score 5):

Add an extra join on the posts table and join on acceptedanswerid, [like so](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/643009?MyAccountID=3632206):

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##MyAccountID:int?3632206##

SELECT Posts.Tags,Posts.Title,Posts.Body, acc.body [accepted answer]
FROM Posts 
left outer join posts acc on posts.acceptedanswerid = acc.id
WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
```